# After upgrade to Lubuntu 14.04 not able to run any command on command line or open a program!

Tags: apt, package-management, lubuntu, dpkg

all commands that I type on command line is returning:

no such a file or directory.

Below I try to write how it has happened.

Recently I have upgraded Lubuntu from 13.04 to Lubuntu 14.04. Then I wasn't able to compile latex files. Unfortunately that has become the least of my problems.

When I was navigating on web to search a way to fix this bug, I found a web page where they gave instructions on as sequence of commands. Unfortunately, I have lost the web address with the instructions, but history command works.So, this is the sequence of commands I have used:

1. `sudo apt-get update` (worked just fine but could not update latex, texlive, and so on)
2. `sudo apt-get upgrade` (worked just fine but could not update latex, texlive, and so on)
3. `sudo dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb` (worked fine but showed some errors)
4. `sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libc6:i386` (worked with few errors)
5. `sudo dpkg --configure -a` (here on almost every command on command line returns: No such file or directory)

I am worried, because I cannot even mount a pen drive and don´t know how to start looking for a solution.

I would be very thankful for any help.

Yours sincerely,

Alexandre

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Hi A.B., whenever I type:

sudo apt-get update:
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

Comment: [edit] your question and add the output of `command -v sudo`

Answer (score 0):

Showing us the exact commands and the "few error messages" would help, but my guess is that by doing the `sudo dpkg -r --force-depends libc6:i386` command:

```
  -r, --remove, -P, --purge package...|-a|--pending
              Remove  an  installed  package. -r or --remove remove everything
              except conffiles. This  may  avoid  having  to  reconfigure  the
              package if it is reinstalled later. (Conffiles are configuration
              files that are listed in the DEBIAN/conffiles control file).

   --force-things, --no-force-things, --refuse-things

          Force  or refuse (no-force and refuse mean the same thing) to do
          some  things.  things  is  a  comma  separated  list  of  things
          specified  below  

     depends: Turn all dependency problems into warnings.
```

and, by ignoring "a few error messages" like:

```
dpkg: libc6:i386: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 libxau6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libkrb5-3:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.16).
 libwrap0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.11).
 libcupsimage2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libcap2:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.8).
 libxt6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.7).
 libasyncns0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15).
 libglib2.0-0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.17).
 libgphoto2-port0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15).
 libwebp5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libpcsclite1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.15).
 libvisual-0.4-plugins:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libstdc++5:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.3).
 libstdc++6:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.18).
 libmad0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 gstreamer0.10-x:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 p11-kit-modules:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.16).
 libxcursor1:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libqt4-xmlpatterns:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libpixman-1-0:i386 depends on libc6 (>= 2.4).
 libpng12-0:i386 depends on libc6 (
 ...
```

You have managed to uninstall `libc`, the main runtime library, and EVERYTHING THAT DEPENDED ON IT.

Until you reinstall, your system is worse than a doorstop - it will eat up  infinite time and produce no results.

Comment: Hi Waltinator, thank you for your answer. Indeed, whenever I type:

sudo apt-get update:
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory

Even worse, my system cannot mount a usb drive

Comment: `sudo` depends on `libc`, so it, too got uninstalled, along with almost everything else.  I didn't quote the whole warning message in my answer, but it included `sudo` later on.  Lesson: Do NOT run commands until you understand what they do. Linux is a Powerful Tool, and will let you shoot yourself in the foot with glee. Learn how to aim elsewhere. Use the `man`, Luke.

Comment: Until you reinstall, your system is worse than a doorstop - it will eat up infinite time and produce no results.